# Ejabberd erlang and async task

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

in a ejabberd module I use this method:

httpc:request(post, {Url, Header

It seems not to be async, is there a way with erlang to launch this on a separated thread???

Answer (score 0):

```
Sample method-
// module name - sample
http_request(Method,Url,Body)->
httpc:request(Method, {Url, [], "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", Body}, [], []).
```

you will call like that-

```
 spawn(sample, http_request, [post,”www.sample.com”,”some sample data”]). 
 %% syntax spawn(Module, Name, Args) -> pid()
```

http://erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html
http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html

Comment: see my reply for the warning

Answer (score 0):

i have used this:

```
    spawn(mod_http_offline, http_request, [Url, Post]).

    % Function that make a call
    http_request(Url, Post)->
      TypeData = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Header = [],
      HTTPOptions = [],
      Options = [],
      httpc:request(post, {Url, Header, TypeData,list_to_binary(Post)}, HTTPOptions, Options).
```

But when i compile, obtain this:

`Warning: function http_request/2 is unused`

and function is not called

Comment: You need to export that function in order to call it globally (which is the case when you use spawn/3).
P.S: You could use async calls in httpc by adding {sync, false} to the Options. See an example here http://www1.erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_client.html#id60384